# PHP: Often complaning about locked (www) files on server

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, php, windows-server-2012, joomla

)

I have a Apache webserver on a Windows 2008 R2 and a Windows 2012 server. Both - but mostly the 2012 server - gets complains from the PHP level about locked files (in the public www folder) that cannot be deleted (which PHP should be allowed to do).

I often log onto the server and delete one subfolder after subfolder - or wait for the nightly restart of the server. But isn't here a smarter solution? Like excluding the www folder from Windows' (restrictive) file locking policy?

When PHP scripts wants to delete files it is OK - windows does not need to keep locking the files and folders (that the PHP script it self has created). This happens every time I install Joomla - the "installation" folder cannot be deleted by Joomla itself and it takes me some time to delete it manually from the server.

Can the www folder be excluded from the file locking server policy that seems to more restrictive on a windows 2012 server than a 2008 server?

Comment: Don't use Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Windows apps are pretty bad with leaving open file handles causing files and folders to remain "locked".  Download the program handle.exe to see what process is locking the file in question, and then you should know how to proceed ( if it is AV or some other scanning program interfering etc).